# Best way to assign score to result of a query based on a grid

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns some data related to some leads, something like this

| lead_id | lead_city | lead_city_rank | lead_category | lead_category_rank | lead_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Delhi | A | apparel | A | 100-200 |
| 2 | Mumbai | B | apparel | A | 0-100 |
| 3 | Meerut | A | shoes | B | 200-500 |

Now based on the values of lead_city_rank, lead_category_rank and lead_value, I have to assign a score to each row. So I have a master grid table for this, which tells the score of different combination of parameters.

| grid_record_id | grid_city_rank | grid_category_rank | grid_lead_value | grid_score_to_assign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 1000-2000 | 10 |
| 2 | A | A | 500-1000 | 20 |
| 3 | A | A | 200-500 | 30 |
| 4 | A | A | 100-200 | 40 |
| 5 | A | A | 0-100 | 50 |
| 6 | A | B | 1000-2000 | 60 |
| 7 | A | B | 500-1000 | 70 |
| 8 | A | B | 200-500 | 80 |
| 9 | A | B | 100-200 | 90 |
| 10 | A | B | 0-100 | 100 |

There are around 300 different such combinations. On this table, I have created a function:

```
CREATE fn_get_lead_score(
    in_city_rank          CHARACTER VARYING, 
    in_category_rank      CHARACTER VARYING, 
    in_order_value        CHARACTER VARYING
)
RETURNS NUMERIC
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $function$
DECLARE
    my_score NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    SELECT grid_score_to_assign INTO my_score
    FROM grid_score_master 
    WHERE grid_city_rank = in_city_rank
      AND grid_category_rank = in_category_rank
      AND grid_lead_value = in_order_value;
  
    RETURN my_score;
END;
$function$;
```

Finally , I use this function in my original query to assign the score and select top 50 records

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT lead_id, 
             lead_city, 
             lead_city_rank, 
             lead_category, 
             lead_category_rank, 
             lead_value, 
             fn_get_lead_score(lead_city_rank, lead_category_rank, lead_value) AS lead_score 
      FROM my_leads 
      WHERE user_id = 10) my_leads 
ORDER BY lead_score ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

But this approach is taking much time specially when there are around 2-3 million leads coming from the query. so 2-3 million times the function is being executed ( for possible 300 combinations ).

Is there any other optimized way to do this?

Comment: Why did you not join the function select to the query, so the fact bction is superfluous

Comment: Why would you implement a function for a simple join? It's like "I need to go to my kitchen from my living room. I will build a car for this task. Why does my house smell like exhaust?". `SELECT t1.*, t2.grid_score_to_Assign FROM my_leads t1 INNER JOIN grid_score_master t2 ON t1.lead_city_rank = t2.grid_city_rank AND t1.lead_category_rank = t2.grid_category_rank and t1.lead_Value = t2.grid_lead_value`

Answer (score 0):

It might help to convert the function from a plpgsql to a SQL function.

```
create function fn_get_lead_score(
                in_city_rank          character varying  
              , in_category_rank      character varying  
              , in_order_value        character varying
              )
      returns numeric
      immutable
      language sql
as $$
    select grid_score_to_assign 
      from grid_score_master 
     where grid_city_rank = in_city_rank
       and grid_category_rank = in_category_rank
       and grid_lead_value = in_order_value;

$$;
```

A plpgsql is basically a black box to the optimizer so you pay the overhead for function call. But, a SQL function is clear to the optimizer and it may inline the function? But then as @JNevill inquired *why implement a function for a simple join*?